# C# - Displaying time in a specific format

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I'm trying to display a time value but in a special format. For instance, if my variable contains 07:25:00, I'd like to display it like that :

> 07H25

I tried to read some things about custom formats but I didn't get anything interesting. Any idea about a way to do that?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) all you need to know about `DateTime` string formating.

Comment: You want to look into .ToString(format) or string.Format() commands

Comment: "if my variable contains 07:25:00", What is the type of your variable, is it a string , a time span or a DateTime ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a formater for it. For sample, try to have a `CultureInfo` object (you could clone the current) which allows you to specify the globalization configurations and change the `DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator` property. For sample:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = "H";

string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm", currentCulture);
```

Comment: If you look at my Example, you dont acctually need to specify CultureInfo, but this is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable a `DateTime`, you can easily use [custom date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with string delimiter like;

```
date.ToString("HH'H'mm")
```

If your variable a `TimeSpan`, you can easily use [custom date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with string delimiter like;

```
ts.ToString("hh'H'mm")
```

If your variable a `string`, you can parse it to `TimeSpan` first then format it like;

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("07:25:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
ts.ToString("hh'H'mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime now  = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Time: " + now.ToString("HH\\Hmm"));
```

output is

> Time: 15H44

and HH denotes a 24hr Time format so you will get 07, not just 7

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-u/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is a reference table for all DateTime format strings.

Adding onto the other answers already given, this should give you enough information to go away and sort out time format to whatever you desire.